# SIM800L EVB not communicating with Raspberry pi 4 serial0

Tags: pi-4

The SIM800L EVB was communicating with the raspberry pi till I updated the bootloader to the latest version so that I can start the raspberry pi from the USB 3.0 memory stick
enable uart = 1 is set in command.txt
raspi-config is also set to serial hardware

I am attaching the port check python program for reference.

I have received the test message from this program before : smsportcheck.py

```
import serial
import time

NUMBER = "00971569716671"

s = serial.Serial("/dev/serial0", 115200, timeout = 1)
#s = serial.Serial("dev/ttyUSB0", 115200, timeout = 1)

def get_at_response(sleep = 0.5):
    #give modem enough time to reply
    time.sleep(sleep)
    r = s.read_all()
    print (r)
    if not r:
        print ("[AT] ERR <Response Timeout>")
        return None

    r = str(r.decode())
    print ("[AT RX]: ", r)
    return r

def write_at(cmd):
    cmd = b"AT" + cmd.encode("UTF-8") + b"\r\n"
    print ("[AT TX]: ", cmd.decode())
    s.write(cmd)

def send_sms(msg):
    print ("> ", msg)
    msg = msg + "\x1A"
    s.write(msg.encode())

#echo off
write_at("E0")
get_at_response()

#set error codes to verbose
write_at("+CMEE=2")
get_at_response()

#get the ststus of SIM presence
write_at("+CPIN?")
get_at_response()

#caller line identification
write_at("+CLIP=1")
get_at_response()

#Set preferred message format to text mode
write_at("+CMGF=1")
get_at_response()

#send sms
write_at("+CMGS=\"%s\""%NUMBER)
if get_at_response(0.1):
    send_sms("TEST")
    #you may have to increase the sleep here depending on the signal strength
    get_at_response(60)
```